# fork of a multithreaded process: all process memory gets copied?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, fork

I have stumbled across an [article](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) describing the pitfalls when forking a process with threads. The author mentions, that when `fork` is done on a process with multiple threads, the entire process memory gets copied to the child (i.e. no copy-on-write occurs). Is it correct? I've tried to look it up in the kernel source code, but didn't manage to find the place when this is happening.

I'm using CentOS 6.3 (kernel 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64).

Comment: Could you point out the claim in the article? I'm having trouble locating it

Comment: In the very beginning of the article: The fork(2) function creates a copy of the process, *all memory pages are copied*, open file descriptors are copied etc.

Comment: The article ignores COW, see the comments: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them#comment-318

Comment: I thought this could be some simplification the author used for general description, but later in the comments, the author mentions the following: You're right, there is the COW mechanism that avoids copying memory, but it's unrelated to how fork() behaves in a multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in COW behavior between a `fork()` call for a multi threaded and single threaded program AFAICT. The regular copy-on-write behavior (or lack thereof) exists.